# How to convert a CNN LSTM form keras to pytorch

Tags: keras, pytorch, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am trying to convert a CNN LSTM for keras to pytorch but I have trouble.

```
ConvNN_model = models.Sequential()
ConvNN_model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(64, 64, 1)))
ConvNN_model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
ConvNN_model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
ConvNN_model.add(TimeDistributed(LSTM(128, activation='relu')))
ConvNN_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
ConvNN_model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu'))
ConvNN_model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
ConvNN_model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))
ConvNN_model.add(layers.Dense(15, activation='softmax'))
```

How to convert the above code from Keras to Pytorch?

Comment: What trouble are you having? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to write a `class ConvNetLSTM(nn.Module):` with a `__init__` and a  `foward` inside the class but I have not much expirience with pytorch and I am not sure if I wrote the correct network inside the `__init__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your CNN in Keras:

```py
ConvNN_model = models.Sequential()
ConvNN_model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(64, 64, 1)))
ConvNN_model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
ConvNN_model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
ConvNN_model.add(TimeDistributed(LSTM(128, activation='relu')))
ConvNN_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
ConvNN_model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu'))
ConvNN_model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
ConvNN_model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))
ConvNN_model.add(layers.Dense(15, activation='softmax'))
```

This is the equivalent code in PyTorch:

```py
class ConvNN_model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvNN_model, self).__init__()
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
                         nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=3),
                         nn.ReLU(),
                         nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2)),
                         nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3),
                         nn.ReLU(),
                         TimeDistributed(nn.LSTM(128, 128)),
                         nn.Dropout(0.2),
                         nn.LSTM(128, 128),
                         nn.ReLU(),
                         nn.Linear(128, 64),
                         nn.ReLU(),
                         nn.Dropout(0.25),
                         nn.Linear(64, 15),
                         nn.Softmax()
                         )
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layers(x)
```

Keep in mind that there is no equivalent module for the `TimeDistributed` class in PyTorch, so you have to build it yourself. Here is one that you can use (from [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/any-pytorch-function-can-work-as-keras-timedistributed/1346/4)):

```py
class TimeDistributed(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, module, batch_first=False):
        super(TimeDistributed, self).__init__()
        self.module = module
        self.batch_first = batch_first

    def forward(self, x):

        if len(x.size()) <= 2:
            return self.module(x)

        # Squash samples and timesteps into a single axis
        x_reshape = x.contiguous().view(-1, x.size(-1))  # (samples * timesteps, input_size)

        y = self.module(x_reshape)

        # We have to reshape Y
        if self.batch_first:
            y = y.contiguous().view(x.size(0), -1, y.size(-1))  # (samples, timesteps, output_size)
        else:
            y = y.view(-1, x.size(1), y.size(-1))  # (timesteps, samples, output_size)

        return y
```

There are a million-and-one ways to skin a cat; you do not necessarily have to create the entire network in the `nn.Sequential` block as I did. Or if you wanted to stick to the sequential method to stay consistent with Keras, you don't need to subclass `nn.Module` and use the sequential layers altogether.